# Displaying a scrolling grid with static labels 

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, grid

I currently have a grid with a set number of rows and columns defined in a ScrollViewer.

What I need to do is give each row and each column a lable (basically another grid cell) on the edges of the scrollviewarea. These lables must not scroll against the rows when the columns are being scrolled or the columns when the rows are being scrolled.

For example, if the scrollviewarea is scrolled horizontally the lables for the rows must remain on the left edge of the scrollviewer as the grid scrolls. If the grid is scrolled vertically the row lables may scroll too. The lables for the columns may scroll horizontally but not vertically, so basically the opposite of the row lables.

Hopefully I was detailed and clear enough in that explanation.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want fixed columns and rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that easily you can write your own custom Grid with programmatically scrolling
take a look at [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/52a62ade-ada3-421a-9e8f-98f0ebefe919)